# Replace a line string in a File with looped list of files paths from a directory

Tags: python-3.x, linux, bash, unix, build-automation

I am writing a python script but open to doing the same in batch script to replace line strings. I have a directory which has few files in it and have a file.json in a different directory. I want to replace a line in file.json with the full path of the files from the other directory. i.e the line would be overwritten every time with list of file path.

This is what I have done so far, cannot get the list to replace the string yet.

Code:

```
import shutil
import re
import os

origin_path = '/home/download/project/'
Source_files='/home/download/automate_proj/file.json'
target_file = /tmp/file.json

for file in os.listdir(origin_path):
   for f in file:
      f = open(file, 'r')
      for line_org in f.read():
         shutil.copy(line_org)
 
with open(source_file, 'r') as sfile:
   with open(target_file,'w') as outfile:
     for line in sfile:
        if "FILE PATH PLACEHOLDER" in line:
            line = line.replace('FILE PATH PLACEHOLDER', line_org)
        outfile.write(line) 

print "DONE"
```

Example, directory and its files

```
$ pwd
/home/download

/home/download/new.txt
/home/dowload/new1.txt
/home/download/new2.txt
/home/download/new3.txt
```

---

Example:

**file.json**

```
"dataSchema" : {
    "dataSource" : "FILE PATH PLACEHOLDER",
        "parser" : {
            "format" : "json"
        }
}
```

So I want to replace or overwrite file.json line "FILE PATH PLACEHOLDER" with list of file paths from the directory each time the code runs.

**Expected outcome**

```
"dataSource": "/home/downloads/new.txt"
```

**The next loop run would be:**

```
"dataSource": "/home/downloads/new1.txt"

"dataSchema" : {
    "dataSource" : "/home/downloads/new2.txt",
        "parser" : {
            "format" : "json"
        }
}
```

Comment: Your file.json and expected results aren't valid json...

Comment: In your `line.replace(...)`, you use the `line_org` variable.  That variable only exists in the context of the `for line_org in f.read():`.  So when you get to the `line.replace(...)`, it will never do anything.  Unless the indentation is wrong in your question...?